# Appium can't run ipa file. And can't create .app file using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, appium, xcode10, appium-ios

We have an application that we are trying to run on a simulator that we then connect with Appium. We have Appium installed and can run it.

It currently points to an .ipa file created with a distribution provisioning profile. Appium manages to install the App on the simulator, but it launches and crashes immediately 3 times.

From what I understand I have to add a Debug .app file onto the simulator for this to work. But I am unsure of how I can go about creating this. I am using Visual Studio on a Windows pc and Remoting into a Mac Mini. Visual Studio only builds it in a .ipa format and I don't know how to generate the .app file.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and Xcode10

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: can show how you initialize AppiumDriver and DesiredCapabilities? What are the error the appium server is showing?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the Mac machine and access to Xcode, you don't have to rely on Visual Studio to generate the app.

All you have to do is, find the xcodeproject and run it on a simulator.
Once you are done with this, just goto `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<YOUR_PROJECT_NAME-SOME_JUNK_CHARACTERS/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/`

and find the .app file.

Comment: There is no xcodeproj file that I can see. Do you know how I can go about generating one?

Comment: It's a cross platform App. I only have a csproj

Comment: Can you see any folders like Android, iOS folders inside your folder structure? After you build?

Comment: These Folders are located on my windows PC that I'm using to remote in with. I can't find them on the Mac Mini.

Comment: That means you do not have access to the Windows machine which is actually building the .ipa files? If so, then you need to ask your developers to create the .ipa file in debug mode, not the release mode.